# Is there any to access textinput (widget)'s text into another class in kivy of python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy, textinput

i am getting a problem in my project this is the little bit information regarding that:--

link given below is the link to my project. For running it you should have to download all the files in a same folder.
the main problem is when you run it you will get three icons one of them is binoculars you have to click on it after that a new screen will be opened in that screen you will have two text input widget including 4 small icons

what i want is:-- whenever i will click on rocket icon i should get the text of upper text input widget is there any way to do so .

link to my project :-----

https://github.com/themockingjester/search_in_depth_app/tree/master/venv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might work (haven't tested it):

```
def go(self):
    # here i want to print entry1 objectproperty value
    print(self.info_page.entry1.text)
```